# Add X/Y coordinate format incompatible with viewshed tool coordinate format in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, coordinates, qgis-processing, viewshed

I am performing an r.viewshed analysis (id: grass7:r.viewshed) in QGIS 3.10.9 with Grass 7.8.3.

My question pertains to the 'coordinates' parameter. When I use the r.viewshed tool in QGIS and select a coordinate by point and click, the coordinate is (eg.) "3661826.152738,5486199.870317 [EPSG:31467]" and the viewshed analysis works as expected.

However, I'd like to perform a viewshed analysis for a large number of points in a point shapefile, so I used the Add X/Y Field to Layer tool, exported them as csv and am now trying to perform the viewshed analysis for each point using the processing toolbox in Python.

When I manually insert the coordinate "3661826.152738,5486199.870317 [EPSG:31467]", my code works fine. However, the coordinate added with the Add X/Y tool are of the format "11.3445, 49.6174" (numbers here rounded) and the viewshed tool using the coordinate parameter "11.3445, 49.6174 [EPSG:31467]" produce no shapefile (and also no error).

I assume that I have to translate my coordinates from one format into the other and that projections may play a role. How can one do that? I have tried to reproject my raster and project file in [EPSG:31467] as well as in [EPSG:4326], though none of this has changed the coordinate format of add X/Y.

Comment: "11.3445, 49.6174" are WGS84 coordinates, therefore you have to use EPSG code 4326.

Comment: Thanks. When I projected my raster layer as EPSG: 4326, the viewshed analysis still seemed to require coordinates in the "3661826.152738,5486199.870317" format. Any idea why that could be?

Comment: No idea, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting your raster to 4326 will give you trouble. Instead, I would try to project your point layer from 4326 to 31467, so that all your data is effectively in your projected coordinate system.

So make sure to specify that your points are in EPSG:4326 when you import them, but afterwards, project them (save them as a new layer) to EPSG:31467, this way they will be effectively converted to the same projected crs and should be suitable for your viewshed analysis.